# Streaming GRPC call does not return when executed in webassembly

Tags: c#, grpc, uno-platform

I am trying to build a cross plattform app with Uno. I have an existing aspnet core server that answers Grpc requests.

Unfortunately I cannot get server streaming to work in my WASM target. When I call a streaming endpoint, no data is returned until the stream has finishished on server side. I tried UWP and the exact same code (placed in the Shared project) worked as expected.

A simple answer-and-return call to a Grpc service is also working with UWP AND wasm.

These packages I am using in my client app:

```
 <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.18.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf.Tools" Version="3.18.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Net.Client" Version="2.39.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Net.Client.Web" Version="2.39.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.40.0">
   <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
   <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
 </PackageReference>
```

This is how I create the GrpcChannel:

```
var address = $"http://127.0.0.1:5052";
var grpcWebHandler = new GrpcWebHandler(new HttpClientHandler()) { GrpcWebMode = GrpcWebMode.GrpcWebText };
var grpcChannel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(address, new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpHandler = grpcWebHandler });
```

This is how I call my API:

```
 var statusApi = new StatusApi.StatusApiClient(GrpcChannel);
 var call = statusApi.SubscribeForLogs(subscription);

 while (await call.ResponseStream.MoveNext(token)) //<- this method does not return until stream has finshed!
 {            
     var response = call.ResponseStream.Current;
     // do something with response
 }
```

On the server side I configured my Status Service like this:

```
//Startup.cs
app.UseGrpcWeb();
app.UseCors();
app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
   endpoints.MapGrpcService<StatusServiceEndpoint>().EnableGrpcWeb().RequireCors("AllowAll");
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages in the browser console?

Comment: There is no error message. The stream is open but no data is coming through unless the stream is closed from server side.

Comment: When using https the stream works as expected. Also on localhost. Seems to be a browser-restriction issue.